# SQL update statement showing OldShippedDate == NewShippedDate (when I change the new shipped date) to try an update. throws sql concurrency error

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to change the shipped date through C# to then filter through to the SQL Server database. When I try to change the date, I get a concurrency problem saying that someone else is accessing that same record on the database. I have used the debug tool in C# and noticed that the old `ShippedDate` is showing the same as the new Shipped Date when it passes through the Update Customer method.   I have tried to go through the code and can't seem to find what is incorrect.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As stated above, I have used the debug tool quite extensively and pinpointed that the original date gets altered to the new date. It then results in my count = 0, which then throws an error.

The database connection is good and has shown to be successful.

Here is the code in question:

```
public static bool UpdateOrder(Orders oldOrd, Orders newOrd)
{
        bool success = false; // did not update

        // connection
        SqlConnection connection = NORTHWNDDB.GetConnection();
        // update command
        string updateStatement =
            "UPDATE Orders SET " +
            "ShippedDate = @NewShippedDate " +
            "WHERE OrderID = @OldOrderID " + // identifies order
            "AND CustomerID = @OldCustomerID" + // ie. another user changed a value
            " AND OrderDate= @OldOrderDate" + // before update completed
            " AND RequiredDate= @OldRequiredDate" +
            " AND (ShippedDate= @OldShippedDate OR " + // either equal or both are null
            "     ShippedDate IS NULL AND @OldShippedDate IS NULL)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateStatement, connection);
        if (newOrd.ShippedDate == null)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewShippedDate", DBNull.Value);
        else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewShippedDate", newOrd.ShippedDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OldOrderID", oldOrd.OrderID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OldCustomerID", oldOrd.CustomerID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OldOrderDate", oldOrd.OrderDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OldRequiredDate", oldOrd.RequiredDate);
        if (oldOrd.ShippedDate == null)
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OldShippedDate", DBNull.Value);
        else
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OldShippedDate", oldOrd.ShippedDate);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (count > 0)
            {
                success = true; // updated
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

to make updates to the shipped date. I want to learn this well, but so far, I am struggling.

Comment: Can you please post the screenshot of the original exception? or copy the original exception message with it's title.

Comment: I figured it out.   had to recode some of the previous lines in the form.